# Sonar Lint issue when walking a directory

Tags: java, sonarlint

I am using the below code to walk a directory and fetch the first file . I am not able to fix the two sonar lint issues . Please help.

```
List<String> result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have such warning, did you update latest sonar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make this change:

```
List<String> result = walk.filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile()).map(Path::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`SonarLint` also state the reason for the suggestion.

> Lambdas should be replaced with method references

[image]

> Java 8's "Files.exists" should not be used

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the 3725 Sonar rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/java8/RSPEC-3725) :

> The Files.exists method has noticeably poor performance in JDK 8, and
>   can slow an application significantly when used to check files that
>   don't actually exist.
>
> The same goes for Files.notExists, Files.isDirectory and
>   Files.isRegularFile.
>
> Note that this rule is automatically disabled when the project's
>   sonar.java.source is not 8.

Your project very probably relies on JDK/JRE 8.
If you dig into [the OpenJDK issues](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154077) you could see that on Linux the issue was partially solved but not on Windows.

About the second issue :

```
map(x -> x.toString())
```

Just replace it by a method reference :

```
map(Path::toString)
```

So finally to be compliant with Sonar, it gives :

```
                           //FIXME use Files::isRegularFile when update with Java>8 
List<String> result = walk.filter(p -> p.toFile().exists())
                          .map(Path::toString)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```